# Find out why Visual Studio decides to copy DLLs into a bin directory

Tags: visual-studio, dll, build

I have a web application project. I am trying to find out why certain DLLs are being copied into the bin directory of the web application. As far as I can see there are no references to the DLLs under the list of references.

Whilst I don't think it should make a difference, I have been through all the DLLS of the projects that the web application depends upon and selected **Copy Local=False**.

But still when I build the solution, the DLLs turn up in the bin directory. I don't want them there. How can I find out what is putting the DLLs there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An indirect reference perhaps?

That is, you reference assembly A and it references assembly B and C. Presto! B.dll and C.dll are in your bin folder. Use [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) or [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx) to check the references of the assemblies you have referenced in you project.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your **Post-build events** which you can find in **Project Properties->Build Events->Post-build event**. There might a command-line instruction to copy a DLL into your `bin` directory.